# exponential numbers in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rounding

I have this problem with numbers in a dataframe in a column named "settle":
For example i have these numbers: 1.170
.920
0
.680
.005
.450
.030
.270

I therefore need to make them into readable numbers and divide them by 10000:

```
df["settle"]=pd.to_numeric("0"+df["settle"])/10000
```

And here is the result after this code:
0.000117
0.0
9.2e-05
0.0
6.8e-05
5,00E-07
4.5e-05
3,00E-06
2,70E+11

So I have as a result exponential numbers that create problems for me, I would need all the decimals up to the seventh digit.

I tryed:

```
df["settle"]=df["settle"].round(decimals=7)
```

but I get this result:
0.000117
0.0
9.2e-05
0.0
6.8e-05
5,00E-07
4.5e-05
3,00E-06
2.7e-05

So no improvements to fix this

Comment: What do you mean by "exponential numbers"? What do you want the output to be?

Comment: I get number like 9.2e-05 and i would like it to be 0.000092
(9.2e-5 = 9.2 x 10-5 = 0.000092)

Answer (score 1):

As you know `9.2e-05` is equivalent to `0.000092`. You shouldn't worry about the formatting until you are ready to print them out for display. Don't try to round the numbers or otherwise modify them. Just format them the way you want when you are ready to print them out. You can use f-strings to format the numbers as strings in whatever way you want.

Comment: It's not working, I tried: df["settle"]=f'{df["settle"]:7f}'
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to Series.__format__